# Trying to set up register form with php & msql

Tags: php, mysql

i made simple form for register and connect it to database.
If i sign up for the first time, it allowed me to login and go to main page.
however after i log out and trying to login again it always shows "Incorrect password or email" even i put everything correctly.
tried to reset password, password successfully reset but when i try to login it just showing me same error again.

heres the register php code that im using

```
//if user signup button 
if(isset($_POST['signup'])){ 
$name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
$email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
$cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
if($password !== $cpassword){
    $errors['password'] = "Confirm password not matched!";
}
$email_check = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
$res = mysqli_query($con, $email_check);
if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
    $errors['email'] = "Email that you have entered is already exist!";
}
if(count($errors) === 0){
    $encpass = $password;
    $code = rand(999999, 111111);
    $status = "notverified";
    $insert_data = "INSERT INTO usertable (name, email, password, code, status)
                    values('$name', '$email', '$encpass', '$code', '$status')";
    $data_check = mysqli_query($con, $insert_data);
    if($data_check){
        $subject = "Email Verification Code";
        $message = "Your verification code is $code";
        $sender = "From: blahblah@example.com";
        if(mail($email, $subject, $message, $sender)){
            $info = "We've sent a verification code to your email - $email";
            $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
            header('location: user-otp.php');
            exit();
        }else{
            $errors['otp-error'] = "Failed while sending code!";
        }
    }else{
        $errors['db-error'] = "Failed while inserting data into database!";
    }
}
```

}

And this is login php script im using

```
//if user click login button
if(isset($_POST['login'])){
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $check_email = "SELECT * FROM usertable WHERE email = '$email'";
    $res = mysqli_query($con, $check_email);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0){
        $fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);
        $fetch_pass = $fetch['password'];
        if(password_verify($password, $fetch_pass)){
            $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
            $status = $fetch['status'];
            if($status == 'verified'){
              $_SESSION['email'] = $email;
              $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
                header('location: index.php');
            }else{
                $info = "It's look like you haven't still verify your email - $email";
                $_SESSION['info'] = $info;
                header('location: user-otp.php');
            }
        }else{
            $errors['email'] = "Incorrect email or password!";
        }
    }else{
        $errors['email'] = "It's look like you're not yet a member! Click on the bottom link to signup.";
    }
}
```

Comment: OT: To prevent [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), I'd suggest to use [prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) preferably with [PDO](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) or [mysqli](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php).

Comment: You’re trying to use `password_verify`, but your password isn’t hashed…!?

Comment: @deceze oh thank you! yes now i think i know why, because the original code come with bcrypt but i get rid of it since i want to learn from the bottom. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you register new user from your register page, you store plain `password` into your `usertable`. Suppose, when you put `password = 123`, it will store `123` into your `password` column in your `usertable`.

But when you try to `login` with same password `123`, your `login` page logic say the password should be verify with `password_verify` method.

This method check the password with `Hashing` algorithm. That's why you are seeing `incorect message`. You may change the login page logic

From `if(password_verify($password, $fetch_pass))` to `if($password == $fetch_pass)`

Or use properly [password_verify](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php)  method.